# Reading records from a Fortran binary file in Python

Tags: python, binary, fortran

I need to read a Fortran binary file with python, named `merg_2015041312_4km-pixel.Z` (from [here](http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/granlist.pl?page=1&location=%28-90,-180%29,%2890,180%29&dataSet=MERG&version=001&allversion=001&startTime=2015-04-13T00:00:01Z&endTime=2015-04-13T23:59:59Z&keyword=MERG&longname=NCEP/CPC%204km%20Global%20%2860N%20-%2060S%29%20IR%20Dataset&CGISESSID=5f3b4d8f2a05c07b147251715602e647&prodpg=http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/collections/MERG__001.shtml)), that is compressed; the structure of uncompressed file is defined [here](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/global_precip/html/README). The definition says that

> Each file contains 2 records: the 1st for the "on the hour" images (":00") and the 2nd for the "on the half hour" images (":30").

and

> Each record is a 9896 x 3298 Fortran array of IR brightness temperatures that have been scaled to fit into 1-byte by subtracting "75" from each datum.

[GrADS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GrADS) .ctl file description:

```
    DSET merg_1999042012_4km-pixel
    OPTIONS yrev little_endian template
    UNDEF  330
    TITLE  globally merged IR data
    XDEF 9896 LINEAR   0.0182 0.036378335
    YDEF 3298 LINEAR   -59.982 0.036383683
    ZDEF   01 LEVELS 1
    TDEF 99999  LINEAR   12z04Apr1999 30mn
    VARS 1
    ch4  1  -1,40,1,-1 IR BT  (add  '75' to this value)
    ENDVARS
```

and I tried to write some python code:

```
>>> import struct
>>> file = open("merg_2015041312_4km-pixel", 'rb')
>>> data = struct.unpack('>h', file.read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2
```

Unfortunately, I'm not used to binary files...

How can I obtain the second record (half hourly) from this file?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was wondering whether there was a way to retrieve its inner structure... maybe I'll look for a GUI "hexish" editor and try to read it that way. Thanks.

Comment: I found this, could it help? `DSET merg_1999042012_4km-pixel
   OPTIONS yrev little_endian template
   UNDEF  330
   TITLE  globally merged IR data
   XDEF 9896 LINEAR   0.0182 0.036378335
   YDEF 3298 LINEAR   -59.982 0.036383683
   ZDEF   01 LEVELS 1
   TDEF 99999  LINEAR   12z04Apr1999 30mn
   VARS 1
   ch4  1  -1,40,1,-1 IR BT  (add  '75' to this value)
   ENDVARS `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107822/discussion-between-ilja-and-urgeo).

Answer (score 4):

From reading the [dataset description](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/global_precip/html/README) and testing with a [dataset](http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/granlist.pl?page=1&location=%28-90,-180%29,%2890,180%29&dataSet=MERG&version=001&allversion=001&startTime=2015-04-13T00:00:01Z&endTime=2015-04-13T23:59:59Z&keyword=MERG&longname=NCEP/CPC%204km%20Global%20%2860N%20-%2060S%29%20IR%20Dataset&CGISESSID=5f3b4d8f2a05c07b147251715602e647&prodpg=http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/collections/MERG__001.shtml) it is clear that the file is a (compressed) Fortran direct-access file with 2 records of IR data of size `(9896, 3298)` downscaled to fit in 1 byte by subtracting 75 from the values. It is not clear if the resulting byte is unsigned or signed, because I have no experience with [GrADS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GrADS) control definitions.

[`numpy.fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html#numpy.fromfile) is a tool for [easily reading binary Fortran direct-access files](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.FortranFile.html).

Use either `int8` or `uint8` as *dtype* to build your record [data type object](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), check which one makes sense. For
example if the data is IR temperatures in Kelvins, using `uint8` would 
result in min 186 and max 330 after scaling (~ -87°C to 56.8°C).
Upcast to big enough type for upscaling, used `float` here, could be
`int16`, `int32` etc.

```
H = 9896
W = 3298
Record = np.dtype(('uint8', H*W))
A = np.fromfile('merg_2015041312_4km-pixel',
                dtype=Record, count=2).astype('float') + 75
```

The resulting 1d-arrays have to be reshaped to correct dimensions and shape. Data type objects would support sub-arrays, but they are [always read in C-contiguous memory layout](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

```
I_on_the_hour = A[0].reshape((H, W), order='F')  # Fortran data order
I_on_the_half_hour = A[1].reshape((H, W), order='F')
```

Check that the results look sane (in `ipython --pylab`)

```
plt.imshow(I_on_the_half_hour)
```

Comment: @urgeo it seems your edits were rejected while I was gone. You are correct in that the images require transposing.